# How to fix WebStorm not recognizing some Node.js Express properties?

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, express, syntax-highlighting, webstorm

After execute `express mysite` and ``npm install -d` I opened the generated directory with WebStorm, the following Express methods aren't recognized by the IDE:

```
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
```

How to fix that?

Note: The IDE was capable to recognize lot of new things after I did [this](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/03/attaching-the-sources-of-node-js-core-modules/) and add module directory as JavaScript Library in the settings, but still not recognize the above mentioned methods. See the image to see what the IDE recognized so far [image]

In this following image you can see what the IDE still not recognize:

[image]

Comment: If you right-click in the editor, select 'Use JavaScript Library', and choose the version of Node you've setup.. does the resolution work?  This is the only thing I've done in addition to your step and express completion works fine for me.

Comment: @JimSchubert Thanks for your reply. What you said is just another way to show and enable/disable the libraries I have defined in the IDE setting I mentioned. Are you telling me that you type `express.` and then press CTRL+Space and *favicon*, *logger*, *bodyParser* show up? and they aren't marked as problematic in your IDE as they are in my IDE? Pls, take a look to both images I pated and let me know.

Comment: I just looked, and I *don't* have completion on express properties or functions, but it also doesn't display in WebStorm as problematic. Hovering over the functions for middleware show that the function is unresolved. That's pretty weird.

Comment: @JimSchubert To get completion on express properties or functions you must add the modules directory as a JavaScript Labrary in the WebStorm settings.

Comment: It's due to the way express loads the connect middleware, seems to confuse intellij. See here: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/express.js#L47

Comment: @furydevoid You are absolutely right. Express is using reflection to map Connect's middleware functions, leaving IntelliJ totally blind. I see no easy way of making Webstorm recognize those middlewares!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This applies to almostly any JS project out there. You should explicitly define an object's properties *or* write JSDocs:

```
/**
 * @memberOf   myLib
 * or
 * @name       myLib.MyDynamicallyLoadedModule
 */
var MyDynamicallyLoadedModule = {};
```

Otherwise, WebStorm cannot understand that you have dynamic properties.

(yeah, I know you're refering to Express, but that's how WebStorm works)

Comment: Has anyone written JSDocs for Express yet?

Comment: You could use TypeScript stubs from https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/express/express.d.ts in WebStorm 7, including the latest EAP. Adding it as a library could also be done in Settings|JavaScript|Libraries|Download.

Comment: @de1mar - Your solution worked perfectly in IDEA 13 Ultimate, thanks! Why this is not included/configured by the nodejs starter project in Intellij is beyond me...

Comment: @de1mar It is helpful if You could add this as a answer.