# IntelliJ Idea 12 Unable To Resolve Express Methods

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, express, code-completion

For some odd reason, I can't seem to have code completion with the "express" object in my node.js project. Here is a screen of it.

[image]

My OS is Windows 8 and I am using IntelliJ Idea 12.11. Perhaps I need to do some extra setup? Please let me know.

Comment: Did you configure the [JS libraries usage scope](http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/148/20130419230701.png)?

Comment: I just did with the defaults. How do I add express to it?

Comment: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6667 may be related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@CrazyCoder got it right, it is indeed a intellij bug, as of now still unpatched, guess we have to wait =( The URL is http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6667. In the meantime, I guess I will have to live with it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are on IDEA 13, you will still not get the Express methods until you use the express typescript stub

go to Javascript Libraries > Downloads and switch the combobox at the top to Typescript community stubs then type express

you should see the stub, it's also here: 
https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/express/express.d.ts

if you are on Java 1.7 and haven't disabled the SNI Support you will get a handshake alert and the download will fail, go to the directory where your IDEA.exe is located and add the following line to the idea.exe.vmoptions:

```
-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
```

Comment: I know this is old, but issue was still there after 1 year. Solution found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16619199/138469